# How to tell Unity not to adapt graphics settings

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, shadow

I've been wondering for a long time why the shadows on the "Very High" and "Ultra" Qualify become cubic (as in the screenshot).
[image]
Although the shadow settings at these Qualify levels are set to the proper quality of shadows. And cubes, it should not be. Second screenshot.:
[image]
Why this happens.: Everything depends on the complexity of the tocation objects, the number of objects, their meshes, materials, textures, etc. In more complex locations, the quality of shadows is distorted (decreased) even starting with the "Medium" level of Qualify and above. But this approach leads to the fact that the settings on the Ultra will not correspond to the name of these settings, which will infuriate the user of the game. Therefore, the question arises: How to tell Unity not to reduce the quality of shadow settings, and other noticeable graphics settings, in complex scenes and, accordingly, with heavy loads?